# Android клиент для сайта

Tags: android, apk, site, client

Опишите пожалуйста этапы, стадии разработки приложения "клиент для сайта". Знаю, что надо парсить html, знаю, что надо создавать отдельно меню, дизайн самого приложения, но в каком порядке не знаю. Делаю впервые. Спасибо за ответ заранее!

Answer (score 1):

1. Изучите структуру сайта.
2. В зависимости от структуры сайта продумайте структуру приложения (кол-во и тип экранов-активити).
3. Пишите код парсинга нужной инфы с сайта.
4. Пишите код представления данных сайта (например организуйте БД)
5. Теперь отобразите это на экране.

Comment: ну вот сейчас занимаюсь парсингом, так чего то и подумал. 

спасибо

Comment: @Владислав, если один из представленных ответов решает заявленную в вопросе задачу, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от него. А вообще - вопрос ваш слишком общий, зависит от мнения и, поэтому, является оффтопиком у нас